# git status on branch don't show difference between local repo and remote repo

Tags: git, commit, git-status

After make any commit in master branch and use `git status` it tells me that origin is ahead of master and it need push.

```
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

But when commit in branch and use `git status` while checkout the branch, it didn't tell the difference between origin and the branch.

```
On branch test-01
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

I created branch `test-01` using `git checkout -b test-01`, and pushed it as `git push origin test-01` and it has several commits.

Sometimes i forget the commits i have done in branches, so i didn't push them. Is there a way i could track the difference between local and remote repo like master branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to track the upstream branch, as these branches aren't currently tracked:

```
$ git checkout test-01
$ git branch -u origin/test-01
```

Or if you don't want to switch context into the branch you want to setup tracking for, you could've just done the shorthand:

```
$ git branch -u origin/test-01 test-01
```

This will set your local `test-01` branch to track `origin/test-01` branch.

After you setup the proper tracking, you should be able to see the tracking relationship between your local and remote branches with the following command:

```
$ git branch -vv
```

[Documentation on git-branch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch)

Answer (score 1):

Try running:

```
git branch -u origin/test-01 test-01
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to tell git to track remote `test-01` branch. Just remember to add a flag `-u` when pushing first time to a remote branch, like this:

```
$ git push -u origin test-01
```

When your local branch already has an existing remote branch, you can do the following:

```
$ git branch -u origin/test-01
```